# How long does it take for overworld monsters to respawn?

Tags: genshin-impact

How long does it take regular monsters found in the overworld (i.e. things like Specters, Whopperflowers etc.) to respawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the monster "classification".

**Common Monsters** have a 12 hours respaw timer. **Elite** run on a daily respaw timer instead. It is also worth noticing that for elite mobs that spaw with a group of common mobs, the common mobs will also take the daily respaw timer instead of the regular 12 hours one.

This means for example that a single hilichurl will respaw after 12 hours from being slain, but an hilichurl part of a Thunderhelm Lawachurl (an elite mob) group will only respaw a day later alongside the Lawachurl.

For a list of other common respaw times you can refer to [this page](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Reset). [Here](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Elite_Enemies) instead you will find the complete list of enemies that are part of the Elite class.